#  target element click child element, get parent attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

I have this code:

```
$('p', 'div.playlist').click(function(e){
  if (e.target != this) {
    val = $(this).parent().attr('songid');
  } else {
    val = $(this).attr('songid');
  }
  alert(val);
})
```

Which corresponds to this:

```
<div class="playlist">
  <p songid="1">Song Name<span class="small"> by Artist Name</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

My problem is that when I click the span with the artist name, it is not returning the songid attribute which I pass to the swf player to change the song, which makes it default to the first song on the playlist, however when I click the rest of the paragraph tag, it works correctly!

Comment: Playlist? That's certainly a job for the UL element! So UL instead of the DIV, and LI's instead of P's. (The rule of thumb is: Whenever you have multiple elements that are siblings and have common behavior/meaning, you want to use an UL.)

Comment: I agree. I don't even know why I used P's, just a lapse in concentration!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('p', 'div.playlist').click(function(e){
  var val = $(this).attr('songid');
  alert(val);
})
```

Since you are binding to the `P` elements then you don't need to check which element is `this`... it is always the `p` element. Your code was trying to decide if the user clicked on the `SPAN` element or the `P` element and the above code just lets the click bubble up to the `P` element and handles it there.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PAZTs/

If you want to disallow clicks on the `SPAN` elements then you can use `event.stopPropagation()` in an event handler for those elements:

```
$('span', 'div.playlist').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PAZTs/1/

Also a side-note: inside your `click` event handler you declare the `val` var without using the `var` keywords (`var val;`) which puts the `val` variable in the global space which is not necessary.

Comment: My original code was the top one, the problem is that when users click the span inside the p, it didn't return the songid attribute.

Comment: I feel stupid now. It was a problem in my ActionScript which advanced the track if the position was the same as the track length. Of course, before the song loaded, the position and length were the same, so it automatically advanced! Changed that now. Gave you correct answer because... well... it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'closest' like below:

```
$('p', 'div.playlist').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest('p').attr('songid')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.playlist").on("click", "p", function(){
    var attr = $(this).closest("div.playlist").data("songid");
});
```

Notice I'm using `on()` and `data()`. You can't have custom attributes in HTML unless they are preceded by `data-`. This was added in HTML5.

This code will attach the click handler to any `p` element inside any `div` with class `playlist`. The handler takes the parent div and gets its `data-songid` value.